# Scatter Plot between 2 images Google Earth Engine

Tags: scatter-plot, google-earth-engine

I have 2 high-resolution images in Google Earth Engine. I want to plot a scatter between these 2 images. But I am getting some error `Missing required arguments to function seriesByRegion(): reducer`. I don't know how to correct this (or if this is due to the images).

First I imported geometry and my Image:

```
var RZSC = ee.Image("users/chandrakant/Max_RZSC_Layer_Trail_3"),
    geometry = /* color: #d6cbbb */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-81.375, -56.125],
          [-34.625, -56.125],
          [-34.625, 12.625],
          [-81.375, 12.625]]]);
```

Then I visulatized the Image

```
var vizParams = {
  bands: ['b1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1500.0,
  palette: ['blue', 'green', 'red']
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 10);
Map.addLayer(RZSC.clip(geometry), vizParams, 'Rootzone Storage Capacity');
Map.centerObject(RZSC);
print('RZSC Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', RZSC.projection());
```

Visualized my MODIS image

```
var MODIStc = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/051/MOD44B')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-01-01', '2017-12-01')).mean();
var percentTreeCover = MODIStc.select('Percent_Tree_Cover');
var percentTreeCoverVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['bbe029', '0a9501', '074b03'],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
Map.addLayer(percentTreeCover.clip(geometry), percentTreeCoverVis, 'Percent Tree Cover');
print('MOD44B Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', percentTreeCover.projection());
\\Here I added Water Mask
var waterOcc = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater").select('occurrence'),
    jrc_data0 = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_0/Metadata").select('total_obs').lte(0),
    waterOccFilled = waterOcc.unmask(0).max(jrc_data0),
    waterMask = waterOccFilled.lt(50);
```

Here I reprojected the image (RZSC) at 250 m

```
\\Here I tried to increase the resolution from 25km to 250m    
var RZSC_250m = RZSC.resample('bilinear').reproject({
  crs: RZSC.projection().crs(),
  scale: 250
});
Map.addLayer(RZSC_250m.clip(geometry).updateMask(waterMask), vizParams, 'RZSC_250m');
print('RZSC_250m Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', RZSC_250m.projection());
```

[image]

Tried a scatterplot here

```
\\Tried to plot scatterplot here (I want just the basic scatter plot between 2 variables)
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(RZSC, MODIStc, 
                ee.Reducer.mean(),250, 'nd').setChartType('ScatterChart');
print(chart);
```

**The error I get:**
`Error generating chart: Collection.map, argument 'collection': Invalid type. Expected: FeatureCollection. Actual: Image<[Percent_Tree_Cover]>.`
and `Collection.map, argument 'collection': Invalid type. Expected: FeatureCollection. Actual: Image<[Percent_Tree_Cover]>.`

**Additional information:**
Also, I don't know why, but the dimensions of `MODIStc` and `RZSC_250m` are different.
For MODIStc:

```
bands: List (1 element)
0: "Percent_Tree_Cover", double ∈ [0, 255], EPSG:4326, 48x73 px
id: Percent_Tree_Cover
crs: EPSG:4326
crs_transform: [1,0,0,0,1,0]
data_type: double ∈ [0, 255]
dimensions: [48,73]
origin: [-82,-59]
```

For RZSC_250m:

```
bands: List (1 element)
0: "b1", float, EPSG:4326, 20818x28371 px
id: b1
crs: EPSG:4326
crs_transform: List (6 elements)
data_type: float
dimensions: [20818,28371]
origin: [-36235,-6107]
```

Also, when I try to use `reproject` on MODIStc, the data looks smoothed and weird (a lot of details are lost).
[image]

Comment: Your second line from the bottom `var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(RZSC, MODIStc_250m, ee.Reducer.mean(),250, 'nd').setChartType('ScatterChart');` does not follow GEE's format `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(imageCollection, regions, reducer, band, scale, xProperty, seriesProperty)`

Comment: @Kevin. Thank you for your suggestion, but this time I am completely oblivious to the GEE format and the fact there are so many ways (I am unsure, whether mine is correct or not). I recently started using google earth engine like 4 days back, so a little more context would be appreciated. I was not able to find some examples or literature, that could work for me.

Comment: I have tried to improve the question with more details. Maybe that would be of some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is a scatter plot where one axis represents value in `RZSC` and the other axis represents value in `MODIStc`. Also, each dot in the chart should hold a pair of values at the same pixel.

To achieve this, you will need `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature`, not `ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion` as you're using.

To use `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature`, you will need to create a `FeatureCollection` that has 2 properties, one holds values from all pixels in `RZSC`, and the other holds values from all corresponding pixels in `MODIStc`. Below is the sample code to get this:

```
var combined_image = RZSC.addBands(MODIStc)
var region = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-83, -20, -31, 13)
var sample = combined_image.sampleRegions(region, null, 250)
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(sample, 'b1', 'Percent_Tree_Cover')
    .setChartType('ScatterChart')
print(chart)
```

In the code above, I made up `region` variable that represents the area of interest (South America) based on your sample picture. You may want to change this to whatever you want (probably the whole world, I guess).

Also, you may have to increase the scale value (currently `250` in the above code) or make your area of interest smaller if GEE throws up any memory error (e.g. 'Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements' or 'User memory limit exceeded')

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Your code was on point for me. The only problem I faced was 'Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements' or 'User memory limit exceeded' as you expected. But that's the limitation of google earth engine. I would love to hear some alternates to this (if you know any, while keeping the scale at 250-1000), as downscaling the whole map >1000 would hamper the results significantly.

Comment: @Ep1c1aN: A workaround to keep your preferred scale and maintain a large area of interest is to export the result to your Drive instead of drawing in GEE platform. For example, `Export.table.toDrive(sample)` will export data of `sample` to csv file (Same can be done for image). You can then draw your scatter plot in, for example, Excel. GEE does not have (or have a much higher) limit for exporting.